# Unable to see in the Unregistered tab of Google Beacon Tools app the Eddystone UID when trasmitting using the Android Beacon Library

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I see the UID transmitted in Locate App from Radius but I am not able to see in Google Beacon Tools app  . I want to register in Google  the Eddystone-UID when I use a transmitter build with the Beacon Library. Code is the following. What am I not considering?

```
    uuid = "0x56987753868952999aaa";
    major = "0x577886654591";

    beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1(uuid)
                .setId2(major)
                .setManufacturer(0x0118)
                .setTxPower(-56)
                .build();

    beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
         .setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19");
    beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), 
    beaconParser);

    beaconTransmitter.setAdvertiseMode( 
      AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY);


      beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.d(TAG, "EMISION COORECTA: ");
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);

            }
```

Comment: They adding 0x in front of your first identifier to indicate it is expressed in hex.  Also, you will need to set the beaconLayout properly on your BeaconTransmitter.  Please show how you do that so I can see if that is set up properly.

Comment: Solution was 0x in front of the first identifier as you said. Thanks!!